# Add proxy client for specific endpoint

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, service, service-reference

My WCF service has multiple endpoints.
When I choose "Add service reference" I see the Service with multiple endpoints (image below)
[image: Add Service Reference]

I don't need proxies for all this endpoints. I need proxy for one endpoint.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio “Add Service Reference” will add proxy clients based on service contracts.  Therefore, one service contract (even with multiple endpoints) results in one client proxy.

The following MSDN link may prove helpful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb628646%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I don't need proxy code for another endpoints in my solution, but if I click "Ok" on above form, I'll get clients for all endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the only way is to go on server side and temporarily disable publishing of the other endpoints ?? ... hopefully you can get hands on the server side's config file.